# Showing form errors with JavaScript in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for an input text field:

```
<%= f.label :first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'required' %>
```

which produces the following HTML:

```
    <label for="user_first_name">First name</label>
    <input class="required" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" />
```

I noticed that if I validate the fields with Rails the HTML changes to this:

```
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_first_name">First name</label></div>
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input class="required" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>
```

But I want to validate first on the client side with jQuery.  So I provide the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#new_user').submit(function(event){
    $('.required').each(function(){
      if(!$.trim($(this).val()))
      {
        $(this).before('<div class="field_with_errors">');
        $(this).after('</div>');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But that produces this code:

```
<div class="field_with_errors"></div>
<input class="required" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value="" />
```

The div closes in the wrong place...any ideas?

mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wrap()` to warp the elements

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

`before()` and `after()` add elements either before or after the target elements and it won't wrap the elements as you expect. Change,

```
$(this).before('<div class="field_with_errors">');
$(this).after('</div>');
```

to

```
$(this).wrap('<div class="field_with_errors" />');
```